# MsgBox AFTER QueryTable refresh is done

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code where I refresh a QueryTable:

```
Sub refreshCD()    
     ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CD").Refresh
End Sub
```

How can I display a MsgBox AFTER the refresh is complete? I've tried to place it right after the refresh, but obviously it ran before it was done since there's no type of callback or something.

I've read about DoEvents(), but I couldn't understand very well or apply that, and don't know if this is right method.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might try putting it in a Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_TableUpdate.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped Would this work in case users hit the "update" button and no changes were made to the data (source and excel are the same at the time of update)?

Comment: a refresh doesn't update individual cells; rather it rewrites the whole query table area.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a class module and sink the events of the querytable, you have both before and after refresh available, like so

```
Private WithEvents qtCustom As QueryTable

Public Function Initialise(qtInput As QueryTable)
    Set qtCustom = qtInput
End Function

Private Sub qtCustom_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    '   After Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub qtCustom_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    '   Before Refresh
End Sub
```